The Clara font family removes bolded characters sequence
I'm using the clara font, but noticed that in boldface the font removes the character encoding "ffi", as in the MWE example below:
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{clara}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    Two "f" character's together are normal: Traffic. \\
    But put them together and you get: \textbf{Traffic}. %Prints "Tra  ic"
\end{document}

Which produces the following output:

I've never seen this kind of issue before, and I'm happy to reach out to the developer, but wanted to see if this is common in any other typefaces. I don't see the issue with Gentium or other fonts.

Unrelated, but please don't use minimal as a document class for MWEs. Despite its name, it's not actually designed to be a usable class. Just use article.

If you use the OpenType version of the font with LuaTeX, then the ligature appears properly: \usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Clara}.

this is clearly a bug, so report it to the maintainer.

the ligature is set up as a triplet rather than two pairs in the lig table, but that's true for both regular and bold. there doesn't seem to be any issue in the .otf font. (at least, nothing which would explain the bug.) so I'd report to the packager rather than the font designer. note that the bold is much less complete than the regular weight: there are significant differences in character coverage. but nothing which would cause this. (and even if ffi was missing, the support package should still supply a constructed version).

Unrelated, "characters" is plural, but not genitive, hence without apostrophe.

the type1 conversion is wrong. the slot for ffi exists, but it is blank. so the bug is in the opentype to type1 process.

There is clearly an issue with the pfb version of the font but you can approximate the ffi ligature with the ff ligature and a dotless i

\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{clara}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
    Two "f" character's together are normal: Traffic. \\
    But put them together and you get: \textbf{Traff\kern-.07em\i c}. %Prints "Tra  ic"
\end{document}


Vaguely related: At least in OpenType main text, the Clara font family is very nice. This, from the perspective of someone who understands fonts.

I ended up using Traff{}ic to break up the ligature, using the \kern-.07em function threw an error for me.

Hoping that the font gets fixed, you can disable the missing ligatures using microtype.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{clara}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures[\char"18]{
  encoding=T1,
  family=\rmdefault,
  series=bold,
  shape=n,
}

\begin{document}

ff fi fl ffi ffl

\textit{ff fi fl ffi ffl}

\textbf{ff fi fl ffi ffl}

\textit{\textbf{ff fi fl ffi ffl}}

\end{document}

The slot for the “ff” ligature is "18 (not standard for T1, actually).


Would there be a way to rather replace it with a 'hand-crafted' version as in David Carlisle's answer? That way one could have the best of both worlds.

@BadAtLaTeX I'm afraid not.
